# Android Studio export apk error: Error: Expected resource of type styleable [ResourceType]

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

in android studio, when i want generate **signed** apk, Leads to the following error:

`Error:Error: Expected resource of type styleable [ResourceType]`

this Class is: https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

How can I fix the error?

`PagerSlidingTabStrip` class:

https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/blob/master/library/src/com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip.java

`values/attrs.xml

https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/blob/master/library/res/values/attrs.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are working with signed apk then use

`@SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")` to suppress the warning. to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

search "TypedArray".

add @SuppressWarnings("ResourceType") before the class where "TypedArray" in.
for example,

```
 @SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")
    public PagerSlidingTabStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                                int defStyle) {...

}
```